# How can I disassemble a function in .rel.dyn with gdb?

Tags: gdb, elf

I have a function `_ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E`(demangled name) defined in a shared library called `libtiflash_proxy.so` and used in a binary `tiflash`.

I know I can disassemble this function by `objdump -d tiflash-dir/libtiflash_proxy.so | grep ...`.

```
 15c1088:   48 8d 05 39 6e 25 02    lea    0x2256e39(%rip),%rax        # 3817ec8 <_ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E>
 15c108f:   48 89 45 80             mov    %rax,-0x80(%rbp)
```

However, when I call `gdb tiflash`, and try to disassemble it in gdb, it outputs

```
(gdb) disass _ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E
No symbol "_ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E" in current context.
```

I know this function is in a `.rel.dyn` section. Maybe because of this, I can't just disassemble it from name.

```
# nm tiflash-dir/libtiflash_proxy.so | grep "_ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E"
0000000003817ec8 d _ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E

# readelf -r tiflash-dir/libtiflash_proxy.so | grep "3817ec8"
000003817ec8  000000000008 R_X86_64_RELATIVE                    3817ee8
```

My question is is there any ways that I can disassemble `_ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E` in gdb?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I call gdb tiflash, and try to disassemble it in gdb, it outputs

That's because the function is not *defined* in the `tiflash` binary.

Since it's defined in the `.so`, you could use *that*:

```
gdb -q libtiflash_proxy.so
(gdb) disas _ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E
```

P.S. If you can run the binary (under GDB) until the point at which `libtiflash_proxy.so` is *loaded* into the process, `disas _ZN12proxy_server3run28run_impl_only_for_decryption2RS17h0667553f3e6e2968E` would work from that point on.

P.P.S.

> demangled name

No: that's *mangled* name. Demangled name is `proxy_server::run::run_impl_only_for_decryption::RS::h0667553f3e6e2968`

Comment: I am quite sure the `libtiflash_proxy.so` library is loaded. Since I can `disas` some other functions in this library.